# Check my solution of: H is compact $\iff$ every cover {${E_\beta}$}$_{\beta \in A}$ of $H$ has a finite subcover.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

### Question:

Let $H ⊆ \Bbb R^n$ 
Prove that H is compact $\iff$ every cover $\{{E_\beta}\}_{\beta \in A}$ of $H$, where $E_\beta$ 's are relatively open in $H$, has a finite subcover.

### Solution:

[image]

[image]

---

I did this solution with my friend. Therefore I posted the solution as a picture. Can you please check my solution? Is it correct or does there exist any mistakes or is there something missing?

Comment: You have a typo, "such that $H = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^n \alpha_j$", should be $H = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^n U_{\alpha_j}$. Otherwise, I didn't see any mistakes in the first part. In the second part, you should _start_ with a cover $H \subset \bigcup U_\alpha$.

Comment: Okay thank you:) ıs this enough to get successful grade for an exam question? @DanielFischer

Comment: You said $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Now in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there are three equivalent ways to define compact sets - a bounded closed set, a set where every sequence has a convergent subsequence, and the one you provided. The two latter ones are much more general than $\mathbb{R}^n$ - are you sure you're not supposed to use the first definition?

Comment: A bounded closed set? But question does nie give any info about this @PedroMilet I need to write what you say in the answer? I dont understand.

Comment: What do you mean by $H$ being compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are proving that when $H$ is a topological subspace of a larger space $X$, every open covering of $H$ in $X$ induces an open covering of $H$ in $H$ and vice-versa.

If this was your real intent, your proof is correct. However I think that this is a little bit trivial to be an exercise in topology...