# Prove that $H$ is compact $\iff$ every cover $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ has a finite subcovering.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, solution-verification

Let $H \subseteq \Bbb R^n$.

Prove that $H$ is compact $\iff$ every cover $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ where $E_{\alpha}$'s are relatively open in $H$ has a finite subcovering.

---

$\bf{Solution \ trial:}$

For $\Rightarrow$

Suppose $H$ is compact.

Suppose $\{E_{\alpha}\}$ are relatively open covering of $H$.
Since $\{E_{\alpha}\}$ are relatively open covering of $H$,

$\exists$ open set $U_{\alpha}$ such that $U_{\alpha} \cap H= E_{\alpha}$

Then,$\  U_{\alpha}$ is open covering of $H$

Since $H$ is compact, $\exists $ finite subset $A_0 \subset A$ such that $$H\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in A_0} \{U_{\alpha}\}$$

Then, $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A_0} $ is a finite subcovering of  $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A} $

For $\Leftarrow$

Since  $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A} $ is relatively open subcovering of H,

$$\{E_{\alpha}\cap H\}_{\alpha\in A}$$ is relatively open covering.

$\exists$ a finite subset $A_0 \subset A$ such that $\{ V_{\alpha} \cap H\}_{\alpha \in A_0}$ covers H.

$$\{ V_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A_0}$$ covers H.

i.e H is compact.

---

Is the proof enough? Does There exist any mistake or missings in the detail of the solution?

Please correct them. Thank you.

Comment: This solution-verification is important for me. I am a new learner. And this is self-studying. Thus, I want to learn properly. Thank you:)

Comment: That's actually the definition of compact: If $\{E_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a set of open subsets of $H$ whose union equals $H$, then finitely many suffice to cover $H$. But no matter how you define it, the equivalence is still useful.

Comment: A very similar question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435240/check-my-answer-h-is-compact-iff-every-cover-e-beta-beta-in-a-o?rq=1. Now, for your question, you said $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. How do you define compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Usually, the definition is a set that is both closed and bounded.

Comment: For the second implication, do you mean to start with an arbitrary cover $\{V_\alpha\}$ of $H$ by open subsets $V_\alpha$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: Dear @Stefan, You forgot to add that the $E_i$ are open.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell: Thanks :-)

Comment: @PedroMilet sorry for dublicate.ı didnt see it. But answers are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first sentence of the second implication is meant to be ``let $\{V_\alpha\}$ be a covering of $H$ by open subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$," your argument is correct.

Comment: Except for this, everthing is correct. Is it? Does the details of the answer is totally correct and enough really?

Comment: Agreed. But the fact that this proof works for $H \subseteq X$, where $X$ is an arbitrary topological space, makes me think it was not what the exercise was asking.

Comment: Dear @Pedro, I think this seems like a reasonable problem for a first course in analysis where one studies only metric spaces and not general topological spaces.

Comment: Dear @Bstr, Yes. I guess you should write $\{U_\alpha\}$ in the first implication, because it is the collection of $U_\alpha$ that constitutes the cover, but I assume this is what you intended. Do you understand why you should start with a cover of $H$ by open sets in $\mathbf{R}^n$ for the second implication?

Comment: @Keenan Kidwell: I agree. Nevertheless, in these courses the definition of compact set is usually "bounded closed set" (in $\mathbb{R}^n)$ or "a set where every sequence has a convergent subsequence whose limit lies in the set" (in a metric space). That leads me to think that it might be a harder problem, that of showing equivalence of definitions in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes, Dear @KeenanKidwell I understand why I should start with that sentence for the second implication $\Leftarrow$. But, I dont understand your first sentence for first implication. What and how should I write $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ ?

Comment: You say "then, $U_\alpha$ is open covering of $H$." This looks like you are saying a single $U_\alpha$. What you want is $\{U_\alpha\}$, the collection of $U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. This is the covering.

Comment: Okay I understand. Thank you so much for helping Dear @KeenanKidwell